# No implicit conversion of Nil to String Error with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

In my app I've created a view which lists all the PDFs in my S3 Bucket, and for this I am using the Paperclip Gem. However I am now receiving this error in my terminal.

```
    Error performing Courts::SyncronizeBucketJob (Job ID: 8424356c-9717-4cca-9d76-4b157bab1065) from DelayedJob(default) in 450.5ms: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
/Users/conorquarry/RubymineProjects/pair/app/_modules/courts/models/ocr_document.rb:46:in `initialize'
/Users/conorquarry/RubymineProjects/pair/app/_modules/courts/models/ocr_document.rb:46:in `new'
/Users/conorquarry/RubymineProjects/pair/app/_modules/courts/models/ocr_document.rb:46:in `block in <class:OcrDocument>'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in interpolate'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:35:in `gsub!'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:35:in `block in interpolate'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:34:in `each'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb:34:in `interpolate'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:556:in `interpolate'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:171:in `path'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:355:in `block in flush_writes'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:352:in `each'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:352:in `flush_writes'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-6.0.0/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:247:in `save'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/paperclip-meta-3.1.0/lib/paperclip-meta/attachment.rb:13:in `save'
```

Looking at the Paperclip Interpolation Documentation I can't see my error, does anyone have an idea of where I should start? Below is the code throwing me the error.

```
   Paperclip.interpolates :document_folder_name do |a, _s|
    Pathname.new(a.instance.object_key).dirname.to_s
  end
```

Comment: The error is on `app/_modules/courts/models/ocr_document.rb:46` where it's trying to load a string but getting nil. What is happening on that line?

Comment: Line 46 is the Pathname.new line I've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The error is reproducible by:

```
Pathname.new(nil)
```

So in this situation, `a.instance.object_key` is nil.

From the [interpolations doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations), `a.instance` will be the activerecord (or whatever ORM you're using) model that's trying to generate a paperclip path that includes `:document_folder_name` in it.

I'd guess `#object_key` is a method defined on your activerecord model and is returning nil.

You can put a `pry` / debugger or a print statement inside that block to see what the object is, then it should be fairly easy to write a unit spec for that method to ensure it returns the correct string.

In theory calling `object_key.to_s` would fix the error but would mean that `:document_folder_name` would interpolate to an empty string when paperclip is calculating the folder path, which may not be desirable.